# Can I obtain Word2Vec and Doc2Vec matrices to calculate a cosine similarity?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am working with text data and at the moment I have put my data into a term document matrix and calculated the TF, term frequency and TF-IDF, term frequency inverse document frequency. From here my matrix looks like:

columns = document names

rownames = words

filled with their TF and TF-IDF scores.

I have been using the `tm` package in `R` for much of my current analysis but to take it further I have started playing around with the `gensim` library in Python.

Its not clear to me if I have the word embeddings as in the TF and TF-IDF. I am hopeing to use Word2Vec/Doc2Vec and obtain a matrix similar to what I currently have and then calculate the cosine similarity between document. Is this one of the outputs of the models?

I basically have about 6000 documents I want to calculate the cosine similarity between them and then rank these cosine similarity scores.

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) says it returns the inferred paragraph vector for the new document. Note that subsequent calls to this function may infer different representations for the same document (you can make it deterministic by hardcoding a seed `model.random.seed(0)`).

Its more common to use sklearn for tfidf and cosine similarity

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

corpus = [
     'This is the first document',
     'This is the second second document',
     'And the third one',
]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
words = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
similarity_matrix = cosine_similarity(tfidf)
```

Doc2Vec uses consine similarity under the hood so I believe you can use these vectors for that purpose.

```py
import gensim  

model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec.load('saved_doc2vec_model')  
new_sentence = "This is a sample document".split(" ")  
model.docvecs.most_similar([model.infer_vector(new_sentence)])
```

This will return a tuple `(label,cosine_similarity_score)` of the most similar documents.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could train a `Word2Vec` or `Doc2Vec` model on your texts. (Though, your data is a bit small for these algorithms.)

Afterwards, with a `Word2Vec` model (or some modes of `Doc2Vec`), you would have word-vectors for all the words in your texts. One simple way to then create a vector for a longer text is to average together all the vectors for the text's individual words. Then, with a vector for each text, you can compare texts by calculating the cosine-similarity of their vectors.

Alternatively, with a `Doc2Vec` model, you can either (a) look up the learned doc-vectors for texts that were in the training set; or (b) use `infer_vector()` to feed in new text, which should be tokenized the same way as the training data, and get a model-compatible vector for that new text.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have approx 6000 documents and each document contains approx 10,000 words, my first analysis after following some tutorials seems to get pretty decent results (i.e. similar words seem to be in the same location on a plot). Do you have a tutorial that you know of for your second paragraph? I have been looking and not found how to do the "averaging" of the vectors. - Do we lose a lot of information by averaging these vectors? I Will also look at `infer_vector()`however I do not want to feed in new text. I simply just want to cluster documents.

Comment: ~60,000,000 words might be OK for word-vectors – especially for those words that have 10+ varied usage examples. But note published `Doc2Vec` work tends to use tens-of-thousands or even millions of distinct docs. Also note that an implementation limit in gensim's optimized code-paths means only the 1st 10,000 tokens of any text/sentence are considered (if you have any longer docs). To some extent, more `epochs` or smaller vector `size` may help squeeze better final vectors out of smaller corpuses.

Comment: Averaging a set of vectors is essentially a one-liner, and you can see it done a number of times in the `gensim` source. In particular, if you take a look at the `WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.n_similarity()` method – https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/f97d0e793faa57877a2bbedc15c287835463eaa9/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L996 – you'll see it take two lists-of-words, take the average of the vectors for each list, then return the similarity between those two averages. But note the average-of-words is about the crudest/fastest way to get a vector for a longer text.

Comment: If you only need to cluster docs that were in your training set, then you won't need `infer_vector()`. You can just request the learned-during-training doc-vectors from `d2v_model.docvecs` – either all of them in a raw array (`d2v_model.docvecs.vectors_docs`) or one-by-one by the training tags (`d2v_model.docvecs[tag_name]`).

Comment: Thanks! I will take all your comments on board. I basically have a time-series of documents. i.e. these documents get released each year but they do not change much from year to year so they are quite similar. - Are there any downsides to running the Doc2Vec model on almost duplicate documents? - at the moment I am keeping the documents year-to-year independent from each other but if you say that 60,000,000 might still not be enough then I could accumulate the documents each year and run the model...

Comment: Both `Word2Vec` & `Doc2Vec` benefit from a wide variety of subtly-contrasting word uses in their training data. That helps nudge the word/doc-vectors into the complex arrangements that are most helpful. If 100 texts are mostly the same, with much exactly-repeated wording, those 100 texts really just overweight the influence of those repeated wordings, & don't contribute as much vector-quality as 100 truly-varied texts would. So: if your 6000 docs are really just 500 docs with 12 slight-updates for each, that could be a concern, & you'd want more training data from the same domain.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I have approx 6000 unique documents a year, so in year `t` I have 6000 and in `t+1` another 6000 documents where the documents change ever so slightly year on year (i.e. they are legal documents and laywers just change the ordering of the paragraphs update some numbers and change some names) - Could I perhaps mix the documents year on year? Say I have data from 1995 - 2019.

Comment: I know that the documents change very little year on year but they do change over time. Can I take data for documents in 1995, 2000, 2005 and 2010 - train the model on all of these years documents and then use 2011, 2012, 2013.... 2019 to update the `doc2vec` model?

Comment: There isn't really an "update the `Doc2Vec` model" op, so not sure what you're asking. And, you can (& should!) try many things, & test what works for your purpose – every dataset & end-goal is different. But in general: more training data is better, and more variety in data is better (because highly repetitive text will be much like a smaller dataset). For some purposes it might be good to mix all years together (large dataset!), for others maybe latest versions are "best exemplars" of docs (& you'd only mix-in older docs if certain words/topics missing, or as inferred vecs for comparison).